Why can't I set HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError on GraalVM native image?
I want to auto dump when out of memory happen using this code
HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.newPlatformMXBeanProxy(
        ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer(),
        "com.sun.management:type=HotSpotDiagnostic",
        HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.class);
bean.setVMOption("HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError", "true");
bean.setVMOption("HeapDumpPath", fileName);

If I compile it using
mvn clean package

it works, but if I compile it using
mvn clean -Pnative native:compile 

The bean (HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean) is null, why is it null?

According to the javadoc for ManagementFactory.newPlatformMXBeanProxy, it will return null if it doesn't know about an MXBean interface with the name given by the second argument.
I think we can assume that that is what is happening here because GraalVM is different.

So how do you get a heap dump for an OOME on GraalVM?
Well according to the GraalVM documentation you can use -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError and related JVM options on the command line just like you can with an Oracle / OpenJDK HotSpot JVM.  But this is only for GraalVM Java 21 and later; see https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/4641.
Alternatively, the GraalVM documentation also explains how an application can generate a heap dump programmatically.  This is the gist of the example code that the documentation provides:
 private static void createHeapDump() {
     try {
         File file = File.createTempFile("SVMHeapDumpAPI-", ".hprof");
         VMRuntime.dumpHeap(file.getAbsolutePath(), false);
         System.out.println("  Heap dump created " +
                            file.getAbsolutePath() + 
                            ", size: " + file.length());
     } catch (UnsupportedOperationException unsupported) {
         System.err.println("Heap dump creation failed: " +
                            unsupported.getMessage());
     } catch (IOException ioe) {
         System.err.println("IO went wrong: " + ioe.getMessage());
     }
 }

Caveat: I am merely quoting the documentation.  I haven't tried any of this.

Thank you, actually i have read the article. After rereading again, I just realize this graalvm argument (-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError) only work on linux and mac. it does not work with windows.

Well I can think of a solution.  ("Friends don't let friends run Windows" :-) )

Another thing you could do is to open a GraalVM issue asking for -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError to be supported on Windows.  Or better still, implement this yourself and contribute a patch ... for all of the other GraalVM on Windows users.
